cloud composer with terraform
I'm trying to create a composer (3) env with this code:
resource "google_composer_environment" "composer" {
  provider = google-beta
  name = "airflow-env-1"
  region = var.default_region
  project = var.project_id

  config {
    software_config {
      image_version =  "composer-3-airflow-2.9.3"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "dag_upload" {
  name   = "data_connections_dag.py"
  bucket = google_composer_environment.composer.config[0].dag_gcs_prefix
  source = "./some_path/some_file.py"
}

But I'm getting:
module.cloud-composer.google_composer_environment.composer: Still creating... [35m40s elapsed]

And then fail with an unknown error
╷
│ Error: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting for Creating Environment: Error code 13, message: Failed to create an environment:
│ Internal error. Please try again.
│ 
│   with module.cloud-composer.google_composer_environment.composer,
│   on cloud-composer/main.tf line 19, in resource "google_composer_environment" "composer":
│   19: resource "google_composer_environment" "composer" {
│ 
╵

I understand that it might be a Quota Limits problem but how do I know what's is short supply?
Any other ideas to solve or at least debug this issue?

Regarding debugging,
try setting the TF_LOG environment variable to TRACE when run terraform apply.

See also Troubleshooting environment creation.

Finally composer 3 is in preview. It can fail.

Please check the tf [code]. I'm not sure if "provider" or "project" can be used inside the google_composer_environment block.
